# Why can't i pop my fragment after a replace?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity that looks like:

```
private FragmentA mFragmentA;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    mFragmentA = new FragmentA();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, mFragmentA).addToBackStack("fragA").commit();
}
```

it merely adds `fragmentA` when it starts. now `FragmentA` has a button to replace itself with a new fragment, `FragmentB` like so:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
FragmentB fragB = new FragmentB();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragB).commit();
```

So i use the button to replace `fragA` with `fragB`. Now, the problem is, no matter what i do (popBackStack, or call remove), nothing seems to ever remove `FragmentB`. What do i do to get rid of `FragmentB`?

Clarification:

if i hit the back key, how do i just get rid of FragmentB ? (i dont care if it goes to a blank activity)

Comment: so do you want fragmentA back?

Comment: @KishanDhamat nope. IDGAFF about it

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `fragB` to the back stack, just like you did `fragA`.  Otherwise it just replaces `fragA` on screen but the `FragmentManager` doesn't know that it should treat it like something on the back stack.